# I'm really stuck on this recursive function question, I need to return the vowel with the greatest count in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, for-in-loop

```
const VOWELS = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

const mostFrequentVowel = function (words, counter = {}) {
    let count = 0
    if (words.length === 0) {
        return ''
    }
    let lastString = words[words.length - 1]
    for (let i = 0; i < lastString.length; i++) {
        const letter = lastString[i];
        if (VOWELS.includes(letter)) {
            count++
            if (letter in counter) {
                counter[letter] += 1
            } else {
                counter[letter] = 1
            }
        }
    }
    let values = Object.values(counter)
    let max = Math.max(...values)
    for (let vowel in counter) {
        if (counter[vowel] === max) {
            return vowel
        }
    }
    return mostFrequentVowel(words.slice(0, words.length - 1), counter)

}
console.log(mostFrequentVowel(['dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'chicken', 'horse'])); // 'o'
mostFrequentVowel(['dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'chicken']); // 'i' or 'o'
```

I'm having trouble updating the counter object to reflect the largest vowel. I'm wondering if it's more of an issue with the for in loop near the end or if its some logic in the first for loop.

Comment: To clarify, you want to count number of words that have a vowel, correct? Not the number of all vowels within all words.

Comment: Yes I need to just return the vowel 'o' for the first one and 'o' or 'i' for the second

Comment: If the later works for you, consider simply using `join` and count vowels from a string of all merged words. I believe this would pass your current demo input.

Comment: If the former definition is what you want, `join` won't work if multiple identical vowels exist per word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the the first return should be called only if words length === 1 (last word remaining in list).
The way the code was written, whenever there is a vowel the first return is called. This if statement can fix this:

```
const mostFrequentVowel = function (words, counter = {}) {
    let count = 0
    if (words.length === 0) {
        return ''
    }
    let lastString = words[words.length - 1]
    for (let i = 0; i < lastString.length; i++) {
        const letter = lastString[i];
        if (VOWELS.includes(letter)) {
            count++
            if (letter in counter) {
                counter[letter] += 1
            } else {
                counter[letter] = 1
            }
        }
    }

    if (words.length === 1) {
        let values = Object.values(counter)
        let max = Math.max(...values)
        for (let vowel in counter) {
            if (counter[vowel] === max) {
                return vowel
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return mostFrequentVowel(words.slice(0, words.length - 1), counter);
    };
};
```

Hope this answer helps your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead :

```
const VOWELS = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

function mostFrequentVowel(inputs)
{
  var max=0;
  VOWELS.forEach(p=>max=Math.max(inputs.join().match(new RegExp(p, 'gm'))?.length ?? 0,max));
  return VOWELS[max]; // <-Update | mistake -> inputs[max];
}
```

Comment: That's crazy that you just condensed everything into 2 lines. I have so much to learn lol

Comment: @DylanWelzel notice I did an edit to the answer, I had forgot to declare the variable max.

Comment: But in the example, this code returns chicken, not the most frequent vowel.
const wordsArray = ['dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'chicken', 'horse']
console.log(mostFrequentVowel(wordsArray))

Comment: @ManuelMB that's right I will made mistake I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you obliged to use recursion???
If not :

```js
const VOWELS = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

const mostFrequentVowel = function (words) {
    const vowelCount = words.reduce((accumulator, word) => {
        Array.from(word).forEach(character => {
            if (VOWELS.includes(character)) {
                accumulator = { ...accumulator, [character]: accumulator[character] ? accumulator[character] + 1 : 1 }
            }
        })
        return accumulator
    }, {})
    return Object.keys(vowelCount).reduce((a, b) => vowelCount[a] > vowelCount[b] ? a : b)

}
console.log(mostFrequentVowel(['dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'chicken', 'horse'])); // 'o'
console.log(mostFrequentVowel(['dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'chicken'])); // 'i' or 'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict'

const mostFrequentVowel = function (words) {
    if (words.length === 0) {
        return null
    }
    const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    let vowelsCounter = {
        'a': 0, 
        'e': 0, 
        'i': 0, 
        'o': 0, 
        'u': 0
    };

    const allWords = words.join('')
    console.log(`allWords: ${allWords}`) // allWords: dogcowpigchickenhorse
     
    const chars = allWords.split('');
    console.log(`chars: ${chars}`) // chars: d,o,g,c,o,w,p,i,g,c,h,i,c,k,e,n,h,o,r,s,e
     
    const allVowels = chars.filter(letter => vowels.includes(letter))
    console.log(`allVowels: ${allVowels}`) // allVowels: o,o,i,i,e,o,e

    const vowelsCounterFinal = allVowels.reduce( (acc, vowel) => { // acc ==> acumulator (the previous state) // currentOrder ==> current value in the loop
        acc[vowel] = acc[vowel] + 1
        return acc // REDUCER ==> Remembers the previous state // return the next state 
    },
        vowelsCounter // DEFAULT TO START WITH
    )

    console.log(`vowelsCounterFinal: ${vowelsCounterFinal}`)
 
    const keyWithTheHighestValueFromObject = Object.keys(vowelsCounterFinal).reduce((a, b) => vowelsCounterFinal[a] > vowelsCounterFinal[b] ? a : b);
    // return keyWithTheHighestValueFromObject // return only the vowel
    return { 
        vowel: keyWithTheHighestValueFromObject,
        count: vowelsCounter[keyWithTheHighestValueFromObject] 
    }  // return the vowel and the count
    console.log('Debigging')
}

const wordsArray = ['dog', 'cow', 'pig', 'chicken', 'horse']

console.log(JSON.stringify(mostFrequentVowel(wordsArray), null, 2))

/*
{
  "vowel": "o",
  "count": 3
}
*/
```